# STM32 Semihosting - SIGTRAP received when printf called

Tags: c, stm32, stm32f10x

Have followed this guide here (http://www.wolinlabs.com/blog/stm32f4.semihosting.html) to get semihosting on the STM32F103 working. Basically my goal is to get printf working over JTAG (ST-Link/v2).

The one change from the guide was that _sbrk was looking for 'end' rather than '__end__'. Here is my linker file.

```
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

MEMORY {
/*Adust LENGTH to RAMsize of target MCU:*/
/*STM32F103RBT --> 20K*/
RAM (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000 , LENGTH = 20K
/*STM32F103RET --> 64K*/
/*RAM (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000 , LENGTH = 64K*/

EXTSRAM (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x68000000 , LENGTH = 0

/*Adust LENGTH to (FLASHsize - FeePROMsize) of target MCU:*/
/*STM32F103RBT --> 126K*/
FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 , LENGTH = 126K
/*STM32F103RET --> 508K*/
/*FLASH (RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 , LENGTH = 508K*/

/*Adust ORIGIN to (0x08000000 + (FLASHsize-FeePROMsize)) of target MCU*/
/*and adust LENGTH to FeePROMsize allocated:*/
/*STM32F103RBT --> 0x08000000+126K, 2K*/
EEMUL (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000+126K, LENGTH = 2K
/*STM32F103RET --> 0x08000000+508K, 4K*/
/*EEMUL (RWX) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000+508K, LENGTH = 4K*/
}

_estack = ORIGIN(RAM)+LENGTH(RAM); /* end of the stack */
_seemul = ORIGIN(EEMUL); /* start of the eeprom emulation area */
_min_stack = 0x100; /* minimum stack space to reserve for the user app */

/* check valid alignment for the vector table */
ASSERT(ORIGIN(FLASH) == ALIGN(ORIGIN(FLASH), 0x80), "Start of memory region     flash not aligned for startup vector table");

SECTIONS {
/* vector table and program code goes into FLASH */
.text : {
    . = ALIGN(0x80);
    _isr_vectors_offs = . - 0x08000000;
    KEEP(*(.isr_vectors))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    CREATE_OBJECT_SYMBOLS
    *(.text .text.*)
} >FLASH

.rodata : ALIGN (4) {
    *(.rodata .rodata.*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.init))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __preinit_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    __preinit_array_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __init_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array))
    __init_array_end = .;

    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    __fini_array_start = .;
    KEEP (*(.fini_array))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    __fini_array_end = .;

    *(.init .init.*)
    *(.fini .fini.*)

    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.fini_array))
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);

    . = ALIGN (8);
    *(.rom)
    *(.rom.b)
    _etext = .;
    _sidata = _etext; /* exported for the startup function */
} >FLASH

/*
    this data is expected by the program to be in ram
    but we have to store it in the FLASH otherwise it
    will get lost between resets, so the startup code
    has to copy it into RAM before the program starts
*/
.data : ALIGN (8) {
    _sdata = . ; /* exported for the startup function */
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.jcr))
    *(.got.plt) *(.got)
    *(.shdata)
    *(.data .data.*)
    . = ALIGN (8);
    *(.ram)
    *(.ramfunc*)
     . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = . ; /* exported for the startup function */
} >RAM AT>FLASH

/* This is the uninitialized data section */
.bss (NOLOAD): {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sbss = . ; /* exported for the startup function */
    *(.shbss)
    *(.bss .bss.*)
    *(COMMON)
    . = ALIGN (8);
    *(.ram.b)
    . = ALIGN(4);
     _ebss = . ; /* exported for the startup function */
    _end = .;
    __end = .;
    PROVIDE(end = .);
} >RAM AT>FLASH
/* ensure there is enough room for the user stack */
._usrstack (NOLOAD): {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _susrstack = . ;
    . = . + _min_stack ;
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eusrstack = . ;
} >RAM

/* Stabs debugging sections. */
.stab 0 : { *(.stab) }
.stabstr 0 : { *(.stabstr) }
.stab.excl 0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
.stab.exclstr 0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
.stab.index 0 : { *(.stab.index) }
.stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
.comment 0 : { *(.comment) }
/* DWARF debug sections.
    Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
    of the section so we begin them at 0. */
/* DWARF 1 */
.debug 0 : { *(.debug) }
.line 0 : { *(.line) }
/* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
.debug_srcinfo 0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
.debug_sfnames 0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
/* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
.debug_aranges 0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
.debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
/* DWARF 2 */
.debug_info 0 : { *(.debug_info .gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
.debug_abbrev 0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
.debug_line 0 : { *(.debug_line) }
.debug_frame 0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
.debug_str 0 : { *(.debug_str) }
.debug_loc 0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
.debug_macinfo 0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
/* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
.debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
.debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
.debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
.debug_varnames 0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
/* DWARF 3 */
.debug_pubtypes 0 : { *(.debug_pubtypes) }
.debug_ranges 0 : { *(.debug_ranges) }

.ARM.attributes 0 : { KEEP (*(.ARM.attributes)) KEEP (*(.gnu.attributes)) }
.note.gnu.arm.ident 0 : { KEEP (*(.note.gnu.arm.ident)) }
/DISCARD/ : { *(.note.GNU-stack) *(.gnu_debuglink) }
}
```

When I debug my program when I use the printf function the call trace is as follows.

1. main() in main.c
2. _put_r() in puts.c
3. __sfvwrite_r() in fvwrite.c
4. _write_r() in writer.c
5. _write() in syscalls.c
6. _swiwrite() in syscalls.c
7. do_AngelSWI() in swi.h

At this stage the 'SIGTRAP' signal is received.

Does anybody have a clue to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't enabled semihosting in your debugger, so the TRAP instructions used for semihosting calls are not being caught and handled properly as semihosting system calls. Assuming that you're using OpenOCD, you need to add the command:

```
arm semihosting enable
```

to your configuration file, or run `monitor arm semihosting enable` in GDB.

Comment: This fixed the problem. A slightly unrelated question is how do I get the printed strings to show up in the eclipse console?

Comment: I don't know as you can. I use a slightly different toolchain (OpenOCD with GDB), but as far as I know, you can only get the debug output to show up in the OpenOCD console, not in GDB.

Comment: I have used the command 'telnet localhost 4444' and can watch the openocd commands from Eclipse being executed. However I still do not see the printf output in the terminal?

Comment: I have got the printf output showing up in the Eclipse console by following the guide on this web page (http://bgamari.github.io/posts/2014-10-31-semihosting.html) Basically just needed to call initialise_monitor_handles() before I used printf.